# XML serialization to send request to SOAP service c#

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xsd

I have a service which requires the request being sent as XML format.

I have an xsd from which i have used the xsd.exe tool to generate a class which that the xmlattributes which it automatically creates.

However i need to populate this class but am having no joy. So I want to populate the properties in the class and then send that across the request to the soap service.

An example of the class is like below. I have only shown partial information due to privacy.

```
public partial class Request {

    private string[] itemsField;

    private ItemsChoiceType[] itemsElementNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Name", typeof(string), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Address1", typeof(string), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Town", typeof(string), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("County", typeof(string), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]

 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public string[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName {
        get {
            return this.itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemsChoiceType {

    /// <remarks/>
    Name,

    /// <remarks/>
    Address1,

    /// <remarks/>
    Town,

    /// <remarks/>
    County
}
```

How can i populate the class and use xmlserializer to send the request to the service.

Thanks in advance

Regards

TJ

Comment: Do you have access to the SOAP service WSDL? You will need this information in order to create the SOAP envelope. The data contract is not enough in order to call a SOAP service.

Comment: Hi, yup have access but that will be ok as i have tested it using soapUI. So the problem is i need to generate the xml which i put in the request. Hence the class population

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i populate the class

As with any ordinary .NET class you can start by creating an instance of it and then set the property values on this instance:

```
var request = new Request();
request.Items = new[] { "item1", "item2" };
request.ItemsElementName = new[]
{
    ItemsChoiceType.Name,
    ItemsChoiceType.Address1,
};
```

> and use xmlserializer to send the request to the service.

Now that's the tricky part. First, the XmlSerializer class, as its name suggests, can be used to serialize to XML, not to send requests. Second, a XmlSerializer will not generate a SOAP envelope which is required by a SOAP service. In addition to the request XML, the SOAP envelope contains information about which method to be called.

I would recommend you using the newer [`svcutil.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to create the C# client contracts from the WSDL:

```
svcutil.exe http://someservice.com/?WSDL
```

This will use the more recent DataContract attributes and you can use WCF client to send the request. This will also create the ServiceContract interface which can be used to call the remote service:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContract(Namespace="http://service.namespace")]
public interface IMyService 
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContract(Action="http://service.namespace/SomeServiceMethod", ReplyAction="*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults=true)]
    void SomeServiceMethod(Request request);
}
```

Obviously in this example you will need to substitute with the actual namespace of your SOAP service and the proper operation name.

And finally you could invoke the operation:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://example.com/myservice");
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, endpoint);
var client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
client.SomeServiceMethod(request);
```

Comment: Thanks will give that a shot

Comment: The svcutil.exe does not create an interface but just the .cs file with the contracts. How can i force to create an interface?

Comment: This means that you don't have a WSDL but only XSD with the contracts. If you don't have the WSDL you can create the ServiceContract interface manually. You must of course know the method name and service namespace.